# $M_1^2+M_2^2+M^2_3=M$ ,where $M_1,M_2,M_3$ are positive numbers and sum of any two is greater than the third, show that $2M ≤ (M_1 +M_2 +M_3)^2 ≤ 3M.$

Tags: solution-verification, question-verification

$M_1^2+M_2^2+M^2_3=M$ ,where $M_1,M_2,M_3$ are positive numbers and sum of any two is greater than the third, show that $2M ≤ (M_1 + M_2 + M_3)^2 ≤ 3M.$

My solution goes like this:

> We know that, $M_1^2+M_2^2+M^2_3\geq \Sigma M_1M_2$. Thus, $(M_1+M_2+M^2)^2=M_1^2+M_2^2+M^2_3+2\Sigma M_1M_2\leq 3M$

But I dont think, $2M ≤ (M_1 + M_2 + M_3)^2$ is true. For then, $M\leq 2\Sigma M_1M_2$, a contradiction. Is the first inequality, valid? Also, is my solution correct?

Comment: You did not use the full force of the hypothesis.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ohh!    Did u mean that we have to use the fact that $M_1,M_2,M_3$ are the sides of a triangle and then conclude that $\Sigma M_1M_2 =\Sigma M_1^2$ and hence, $M_1=M_2=M_3$ and whence conclude the triangle is equilateral?

Comment: Let $M_1+M_2-M_3=2x$, $M_2+M_3-M_1=2y$, $M_3+M_1-M_2=2z$, then $x$, $y$, $z>0$, and $M_1=y+z$, $M_2=x+z$, $M_3=x+y$. So $M=2\left(\sum x^2+\sum xy\right)$. Then both inequalities are easy. This is another method.

Comment: @youthdoo Indeed that's so true! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one on the right is CS inequality, for the one on the left. Use: $M_1+M_2 > M_3 \implies M_1M_3+M_2M_3 > M_3^2$. Do the same for two more inequalities of the same type and add them up. Then add both sides to $M_1^2+M_2^2+M_3^2$ to complete the square.

Comment: But what about the contradiction I posed?...

Comment: Your contradiction is wrong. It should be: $M \le 2\displaystyle \sum M_1M_2$.

Comment: Well $(M_1-M_2)^2+(M_1-M_3)^2+(M_2-M_3)^2\geq 0$ and so, we have $M=\Sigma M_1^2\geq \Sigma M_1M_2$  

Comment: You are wrong because that assumption leads to the one I mentioned above. You missed the $2$ in front of the sum. That means there is no contradiction at all.

Comment: I remain highly obsecreted for your travail to answer my question and providing with all the circumstantial elucidation for the context. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, Franklin.